# Attribute Error: "List" object has no attribute getFeatures

Tags: qgis-plugins, pyqgis, qgis-2

I am developing a plugin that checks for multipart geometry in a layer in qgis 2.6. I am geeting an error list object has no attribute getFeatures. My code snippet is attached below.

```
def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Clear the QcomboBox before loading layers
    self.dlg.multipartcombo.clear()
    #self.dlg.multipartcombo.clear()
    layer = self.iface.mapCanvas().layers()
    for layer in layer:
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
            self.dlg.multipartcombo.addItem( layer.name(), layer )
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    # Find all multipart features in the active layer
    if result:
        layer = self.dlg.multipartcombo.itemData(self.dlg.multipartcombo.currentIndex())
        iter = layer.getFeatures()
        geoms = []
        for feature in iter:
            geom = feature.geometry()
            if geom.isMultipart():
                layer.select(feature.id())
                geoms.append(geom)
                if result  == 1:
                    index = self.dlg.featurecombo.currentIndex()
                    layer = self.dlg.featurecombo.itemData(index)
                    if layer > 0:
                        QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(), 'There are %i multipart features in this layer' % len(geoms))
                    else:
                        QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(),"Warning!",'Load a layer!')
```

Comment: Looks like [Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute getFeatures](http://gis.stackexchange.com/revisions/132947/1) is solved isn't it? As for [The result is not displayed after OK is pressed in my plugin](http://gis.stackexchange.com/revisions/132947/2), that would be a different question, consider posting it separately. (Template taken from [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify which layer you want to get features from.

In your code, `layers` is a list of layers, whereas `layer` is a specific layer.

You can only call `getFeatures()` from a vector layer.

Additionally, you probably want to get the selected layer from your QComboBox. So, try something like this (didn't test it, probably needs some adjustment):

```
if result:
    layer = self.dlg.multipartcombo.itemData(self.dlg.multipartcombo.currentIndex())
    iter = layer.getFeatures()
    ...
```